# Yeoman cannot find 'underscore.string' when using generator for web

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite Version 10.10.3 and I'm very new to the process of developing web apps. I have bower, npm, and yeoman installed on my system, but the webapp generator keeps on returning an error when I'm trying to generate my scaffolding.

```
Justins-iMac-2:testapp JRS$ yo webapp
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'underscore.string'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/app/index.js:8:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug where underscore.string is set as a devDependency. I've made [a PR for it](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/pull/562).

In the mean time you can install it manually.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/ && npm install underscore.string
```

Comment: The PR is released in v0.6.2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I had to use the following command to resolve this:

> npm install -g underscore.string

in any command prompt window.